# Is Volume distribution for Geometry Nodes available at the moment?

Tags: geometry-nodes

If it is, how can I achieve the effect?

[image]

Comment: Not yet https://developer.blender.org/T85898

Comment: Thank you for the info.

Comment: You can use (hair) particles that are rendered as a cube to get this effect

Answer (score 3):

well, it is a really easy setup:

[image]

grid is this:

[image]

the object with the geometry node itself is just a cube, from which you delete all vertices. That's it.

and you will get:

[image]

for 3.0 you can use this:

[image]

Comment: Upvote for a nice workaround :). Sometimes the result is more important than how we got there :).

Comment: Thank you Jachym!!

Comment: How can I do this in 3.0?

Comment: i updated my answer